# finding chessboard corners with GPUImage

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I used OpenCV (cv::findChessboardCorners) to find chessboard corners in iOS app, but the performance is not where I need it to be. What is a best (fastest/most reliable) way to detect chessboard corners with GPUImage? Is there another GPU accelerated library for iOS that would make sense to evaluate for chessboard detection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want the GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter or its variants to do this right now. You set a block on that which will return an array of detected corners (in normalized view coordinates) and the number of total corners detected. See the FilterShowcase and feature detection sample applications for how this works in practice.

I am working on a faster corner detector, as well as a means of not having to raster over all image pixels on the CPU to extract the final corner points. Both of those should improve corner detection performance, but you can work with the above for now.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Edge detection works really good in GPUImage. Is there a way to do chain egde detection and corner detection (or a reason not to do it)?

Comment: @Rupert - Not quite sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to do line detection? If so, take a look at my (currently rough, admittedly) Hough line detector. It's a little noisy at the moment, until I get better non-maximum suppression in it.

Comment: I need to find a location of the chessboard in the image. HarrisCornerDecetionFiler somehow misses half of my chessboard, but I do see the chessboard outline with every little square really clear with edge detectors. So to improve locating the chessboard I'm thinking: 1. convert to gray scale, 2. find edges in the image, 3. filter down to those edges that belong to the board.

Comment: @Rupert - You can try adjusting the sensitivity parameters of the Harris corner detector (try with the FilterShowcase example for a live preview of this). Also, it operates over a single size scale, so it may not be catching corners on a larger scale. You could try reducing the size of the image fed into the corner detector to have it operate over a larger scale when detecting corners. Also, I think it's limited to a set number of maximum corners it can detect at once right now.